# How to momentarily disable UISwitch while waiting for an event?

Tags: events, bluetooth, controls, uiswitch

I'm trying to momentarily disable my UISwitch control while waiting for an event. After that event happens I want my switch to re-enable. I'm trying to make the control toggle bluetooth, so I need to wait till bluetooth is powered before I can toggle it off again. If I don't disable it, chances are my UISwitch is gonna go out of synch in relation to bluetooth power. BTW, I'm using Apple's private framework, BluetoothManager. (I do realize I can't upload this app to the App Store, but the app's for personal use.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
mySwitch.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

?

Comment: Not exactly, I want for it to wait for an even for it to become enabled. Not instantaneous, but thanks for giving it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

`UISwitch` inherits from `UIControl`, which has a property called `enabled`. Just set this. Basically gets the same result as Fry's answer, which I'm not too sure from your comment why you didn't accept. Eg:

```
// Presumably you're opening bluetooth using a block, so if it hasn't finished yet ...
if (!bluetooth) {
bluetoothSwitch.enabled = NO;
}
```

Then when the bluetooth setter gets called by the block initialising it:

```
// If initialisation was successful re-enable
if (_bluetooth) {
bluetoothSwitch.enabled = YES
// Then just update the view containing the switch
}
```